# Docker Apache graceful shutdown

Tags: linux, apache, shell, unix, docker

We are trying to make OS signals (`TERM`,`KILL` etc) reach the Apache server ,which is started using a shell script. Here is what we are trying to do :-

1) We have a docker file which ends at :

```
 CMD ["sh","-c","/apps/scripts/run.sh" ]
```

The idea is to start apache and hold the docker container  onto it .

2) Then we have a shell script `run.sh`:-

```
_term() {
  echo "Caught signal!"
  apachectl -k graceful-stop
}

trap _term SIGINT SIGTERM SIGWINCH

apachectl start &

PID=$!

echo "APACHE PID is ${PID}"

wait $PID

trap - SIGINT SIGTERM SIGWINCH

wait $PID

EXIT_STATUS=$?

echo "Exiting with Exit Status of ${EXIT_STATUS}"
```

---

The idea is to wait for Apache server and gracefully kill it when it receives `SIGTERM`/`SIGINT`/`SIGWINCH`.

The problems that we are facing is :-

1) Upon running the docker container ,which in turn executes the script , it throws the following error and exits :

> wait: pid 102 is not a child of this shell

Seems like the shells script is not considering `apachectl start &` as it's child process.

How do we ensure that shell script sends the signal to apache?

Any help as to how to go about it would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to do this? For the official [httpd](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/) image, the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/b13054c7de5c74bbaa6d595dbe38969e6d4f860c/2.4/Dockerfile) command just runs `httpd` in foreground mode.

Comment: @EltonStoneman yes.. this is a requirement!.... any idea as to how do we direct logs of apache to STDOUT which is running as a background process?

Comment: what about `apachectl -k graceful-stop` ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like [dumb-init](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init) works well for this. You can use `-r 15:28` to rewrite `SIGTERM` to `SIGWICH`. `SIGWICH` [is the same](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/stopping.html) as `graceful-stop`.

So your Dockerfile will have something like:
`CMD ["dumb-init", "-v", "--rewrite", "15:28", "apachectl -D FOREGROUND"]`

Output looks like:

```
[core:notice] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
[dumb-init] Received signal 15.
[dumb-init] Translating signal 15 to 28.
[dumb-init] Forwarded signal 28 to children.
[mpm_event:notice] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[dumb-init] Received signal 17.
[dumb-init] A child with PID 16701 exited with exit status 0.
[dumb-init] Translating signal 15 to 28.
[dumb-init] Forwarded signal 28 to children.
[dumb-init] Child exited with status 0. Goodbye.
```

Comment: works as a charm, thanks a lot